# sed: Appending after a block

Tags: regex, sed, append

I am very new to sed, and everything I find is a little bit here, a little bit there.

I have a text file which contains a block like the following:

```
#start
a
b
c


#whatever
…
```

Obviously, that’s a simplified version. I would like to append a line to the end of the `#start` block to give me:

```
#start
a
b
c
d

#whatever
…
```

I can sort of locate the block with the following:

```
sed -n '/^#\s*start/,/^$/ p' data.txt
```

so I think that’s in the right direction. However:

- the selection includes the empty line, which I don’t want
- I can’t work out how to add another line after the match

Comment: There won’t be any gaps in the block itself. There may be multiple newlines after the block.

Comment: @Tiw GNU sed version 4.2.1

Comment: Maybe you need `i` command `sed -e '/#start/,/^$/{/^$/i\d' -e '}' data.txt`

Comment: Maybe I thought too much, but you don't have blocks that are consecutive, no empty lines between?

Comment: That's not the right direction. sed is the right tool for doing s/old/new on individual lines but that is all - for anything else there are other tools you should be using for clearer, simpler, more robust, more portable, and more efficient results.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With sed:

```
sed '/#start/,/^$/ s/^$/d/;' file
```

- `/#start/,/^$/`: search for blocks starting with `#start` and ending with a blank line
- `s/^$/d/`: replace matching blank line with a `d`

If you want to add the string before the blank line:

```
sed '/#start/,/^$/{/^$/{s//d/;G;};}' file
```

Comment: Thanks, this does the job nicely, and is simple enough for me to understand. As an additional question, is it possible to insert the new line _before_ the blank line? Otherwise it ends up consuming the blank line, and I will soon run out of them …

Comment: I edited my answer. You can do it with a `G` command that will insert a blank line after the one that has been replaced with `d`.

Comment: @SLePort Brilliant. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

For GNU sed, try this please (update again, had a little bug):

```
sed '/^#\s*start/{x;s/.*/d/;x;be};/^\s*#[a-zA-Z]*/{x;G;x;s/.*//;x;};/^\s*$/{x;};:e'
```

Eg:

```
$ cat file                                                               
#start                                                                   
a                                                                        
b                                                                        
c                                                                        


#whatever                                                                
...                                                                      

$ cat file2                                                              
#start                                                                   
a                                                                        
b                                                                        
c                                                                        
#whatever                                                                
...                                                                                                       
$ sed '/^#\s*start/{x;s/.*/d/;x;be};/^\s*#[a-zA-Z]*/{x;G;x;s/.*//;x;};/^\s*$/{x;};:e' file  
#start                                                                   
a                                                                        
b                                                                        
c                                                                        
d                                                                        


#whatever                                                                
...                                                                      

$ sed '/^#\s*start/{x;s/.*/d/;x;be};/^\s*#[a-zA-Z]*/{x;G;x;s/.*//;x;};/^\s*$/{x;};:e' file2 
#start                                                                   
a                                                                        
b                                                                        
c                                                                        
d                                                                        
#whatever                                                                
...
```

This `sed` command will shuffle those `not-so-empty` empty lines (only spaces lines). But I guess it's ok for you, right?
The idea is to use `hold space` to keep the thing needs append (`d` here), and append it when time comes.
`x` is to exchange `hold space` with `pattern space`(current read-in line).

Btw, if there're multiple `#start` blocks, it will append to all of them, if you don't want this behavior please comment.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `awk` quite simply like so:

```
awk -v RS= '/#start/{$0 = $0 ORS "d\n"} 1' file
```

If `#start` is not at the top of the file the you'll want to do:

```
awk -v RS= '/#start/{$0 = $0 ORS "d"} {$0 = $0 ORS} 1' file
```

*This removes all but one linefeed between each block.

**Result**:

```
#start
a
b
c
d

#whatever
…
```

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed '/^#start/,/^\s*$/!b;/^\s*$/c\d' file
```

Focus on the range of lines between a line starting `#start` and an empty line. If the line is empty, change it to a `d`.

N.B. The `!` negates the match and the `b` with out a place holder, bails out of any further processing by sed.

For comparison, note the behaviour of these solutions which in the first case inserts `d` before the empty line and in the second, appends `d` following the empty line.

```
sed '/^#start/,/^\s*$/!b;/^\s*$/i\d' file

sed '/^#start/,/^\s*$/!b;/^\s*$/a\d' file
```

Answer (score -1):

With any awk in any shell on any UNIX box:

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{RS=""; ORS="\n\n"; FS=OFS="\n"} $1=="#start"{$(NF+1)="d"} 1' file
#start
a
b
c
d

#whatever
…
```

Unlike the currently accepted sed solution the above will work even if the target string contains regexp metacharacters and even if the string to be added contains backreferences and even if either of them contains delimiters (`/`) and it can be trivially modified to make the change based on the value of the 2nd, 3rd, or any other line of the input block rather than or in addition to just the first line and it can be trivially modified to add or modify any line in the middle of the block. In short it's a vastly superior approach.